# Axios post method body is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Sorry, I am new in axios using. What is correct way to write axios post method? Now 'body' is undefined. This is in api.js file, i will import it and pass in another component 'body'.

Thank you in advance

**EDITED**:

So, my question was about axios, now I desiced to know more, because I am new in this technologies.

I just need to pass restaurant id (from props) and feedback text forward to backend and there save it to DB. I don't know how to write this code perfectly, but logic is written in comments. I will appreciate all your advices because I want to learn how this works.

```
import axios from 'axios';

class Api {

  post(endpoint) {
    return axios.post(endpoint, body)
      .then((response) => {
        return { error: null, data: response.data };
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return { error: error };
      });
  }
}

export default new Api();
```

**and this**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../../styles/feedback-send.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Api from '../../services/api';

class FeedbackSend extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      // e.g. body: [], here I want to store array with props of restaurant id
    };
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
      // here I want to add user's input to body (textInput)
    });
    Api.post('feedback/add', { body }) // here I want to pass rest.id and user's input to POST method body
      .then(this.state.isLoading(false));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form.Group className="m-0">
          <Form.Control
            className="textFeedback"
            as="textarea"
            type="text"
            rows="3"
            placeholder="feedback"
            ref={this.textInput}
          />
          <Button
            className="btnFormSend"
            variant="outline-success"
            onSubmit={this.onSubmit()}
          >
            Send Feedback
          </Button>
        </Form.Group>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

FeedbackSend.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

export default FeedbackSend;
```

Comment: You don't seem to be supplying a definition for the name body...

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is in api.js file, i will import it and pass in another component.

Comment: But you haven't defined a parameter for it, even. Please give a [mre], **as text**.

Comment: add body as parameter of your post function : post(endpoint, body) {

Comment: @jonrsharpe i've edited description

Comment: @Aznhar sorry but i can't understant you

Comment: And it *still* doesn't accept a body... Why wouldn't body be undefined? It's not a parameter, even though you try to pass one.